# Need help with a linq query please!

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to write a query that will search for "orders" that contain a certain "product" and I'm having a little difficulty getting it to work.  Basically, this is what I'm trying to do:

```
Dim orders = From o in db.Orders _
             Where o.OrderProducts.Contains(Function(p) p.ProductID = 123) _
             Select o
```

I've also tried with ...

```
Where o.OrderProducts.Where(Function(p) p.ProductID = 123)
```

but that doesn't work either.  Where am I going wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you please tell us what "it doesn't work" means?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: The errors would likely be similar to the following: `Contains()` would expect to receive an object of type `OrderProduct` instead of a lambda expression, while `Where()` returns a collection (probably `IQueryable<OrderProduct>`) instead of a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Any()`

```
Dim orders = From o in db.Orders _
             Where o.OrderProducts.Any(Function(p) p.ProductID = 123) _
             Select o
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I didn't know about the .Any() operator... What exactly does that do?  I tried searching "linq to sql any" but any seems to be way too common of a word to get practical results back.

Comment: It functions exactly the same way you expected `Contains()` to. It will look for any item within the collection (o.OrderProducts in this case) that meets the condition provided. If it finds an item, it will short-circuit and return true, or it will keep looking until the end of the collection (and return false if it doesn't find an item).